# Configuring OpenWRT router to direct all traffic through OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, openwrt

I'm trying to set up a wifi network where all traffic will be routed through a VPN. To accomplish this, I've set up an OpenVPN server according to [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04), and I have a [Linksys EA8500](https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/linksys_ea8500) router which I've set up with OpenWRT and its [OpenVPN implementation](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/client). So far, so good...

What I don't understand and would really appreciate some help with is how to configure OpenVPN on my router as a client, using the configuration I created in that server guide, and get it connecting to my server and directing traffic through it.

I've found and tried to adapt instructions for similar setups from various other VPN providers, as well as trying to fumble my way through some outdated OpenVPN based guides I dug up, but because I don't really know what I'm doing here I'm working blind, and keep getting hung up when things deviate from the recipe.

Can anyone point me to good guidance on this subject, or (and for this you would be a real hero) help me properly understand what I'm doing so that I can make it over the little hurdles and deviations on my own?